# How do I get the photos off my iPhone to my Windows PC without using iCloud?

Tags: iphone, photos

Used to be I plug in my iPhone and there was a drive under This PC for the iPhone and I use Windows photo synchronization to copy the photos from the phone to the PC. However, now when I plug in the phone, it's not showing the phone at all! iTunes pops up and I can back up the phone in iTunes, but I don't see the phone in Windows Explorer in order to copy the photos! It worked just last month.

[image]

Windows 8.1, iOS 8.4

Comment: I installed an iOS update and also some Windows updates and it worked. I don't know why, because I restarted my phone already and that didn't help.

Comment: If you could write it down as an answer (ideally explaining which updates solved the problem), you can accept it and make it useful to future visitors.

Comment: Make it easy on yourself: Just have Dropbox handle your photo syncing ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed an iOS update and also some Windows updates and it worked. I don't know why, because I restarted my phone already and that didn't help. I didn't have to restart my computer. The phone now appears in 'This PC'.